# Saving outerHTML cause System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#

I am trying to save HTML page using c# `webBrowser`

```
var doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
string s1 = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

And I am getting this Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in texas project.exe

Additional information: Could not get the outerHTML property. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
```

Why in different runs I am getting it some times? and how to save the page without this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In different runs you have a different virtual memory utilization, so that is the reason why the app goes out of memory only in certain cases. To know what is exactly causing the app to go over the limit i would suggest profiling with a good memory profiler. Maybe there is something else in your app that is leaking memory and causing the issue.

Accessing the document through the DomDocument API could be unnecessary if your only goal is to get the document string, and not traverse the document.

I would suggest using the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` property to get the whole document as a string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There is also a `WebBrowser.DocumentStream` property in case you want to read the document in chunks, send it over the network as a stream etc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is the difference between `DomDocument` and `DocumentText` ?

Comment: DomDocument is an unmanaged object containing a complex API to access, traverse and manipulate the DOM of the current web page loaded in the browser object. On the other end DocumentText is a simple and lean string property containing the textual representation (HTML string) of the current page.